# Mixture of two gaussians with equal mean

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose we have two gaussians $X_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_{x_1}^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(0,\sigma_{x_2}^2)$. Let $Y$ be the mixture of these two gaussians with weights $p$ and $1-p$, so:

$f_Y(y) = p N(0,\sigma_{x_1}^2) + (1-p)N(0,\sigma_{x_2}^2)$

Since the means are equal, according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution), $Y$ is also a gaussian. I want to find the distribution of $Y$. $Y$ clearly has a zero mean, but what's the variance of $Y$? I'm tempted to write $\sigma_Y^2 = p^2\sigma_{x_1}^2 + (1-p)^2\sigma_{x_2}^2$ but I'm not sure if it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sigma_Y^2 = p^2\sigma_{x_1}^2 + (1-p)^2\sigma_{x_2}^2$  is correct. To show this suppose $U$ takes values $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $1-p$ and $p$. Let $U, X,Y $ be **independent** with $X$ and $Y$ having distributions $N(0,\sigma_{x_1^{2}})$ and $N(0,\sigma_{x_2^{2}})$. Then $UX+(1-U)Y$ has the same distribution as $Y$ and it is easy to compute the variance of this r.v..